# SQL search for missing one of two entries

Tags: sql-server

All records have several entries in the “image_sub_type” column.

I want to search for 2 entries, “link ltr” and “video” and want all records with "link ltr" but missing the "video" entry.

The query below lists all records that have “link ltr” with or without "video" but I only want "link ltr" with missing "video".

```
SELECT M.INCIDENT_ID
FROM TB_IMAGE M
JOIN TB_DIRECTORY D ON D.DIRECTORY_ID = M.DIRECTORY_ID
WHERE D.DIRECTORY_ID = 104
AND m.image_sub_type IN ('link ltr')
AND m.image_sub_type NOT IN ('video')
```

### Output examples:

I can get this:

```
INCIDENT_ID image_sub_type
376815      LINK LTR
397890      LINK LTR
398831      LINK LTR
398831      VIDEO
399066      LINK LTR
399443      LINK LTR
399690      LINK LTR
399690      VIDEO
401045      LINK LTR
401045      VIDEO
```

But I want this:

```
INCIDENT_ID image_sub_type
376815      LINK LTR
397890      LINK LTR
399066      LINK LTR
399443      LINK LTR
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `left join on dir_id=dir_id AND image_sub_type is null`?

Comment: show some sample input and desired output

Comment: Hi there, I added an output example and hope that helps you in trying to help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all records that *has* 'link ltr', but *not* 'video', you could do two joins to the tb_directory table:

- an inner join only link ltr records two only include records with 'link ltr'
- a left join/is null for 'video' to only include records which does not have 'video'

Like this:

```
SELECT MLink.INCIDENT_ID
FROM TB_IMAGE MLink
    LEFT JOIN TB_IMAGE MVideo ON MLink.INCIDENT_ID = MVideo.INCIDENT_ID AND MVideo.image_sub_type = 'video'
    JOIN TB_DIRECTORY D ON D.DIRECTORY_ID = MLink.DIRECTORY_ID
WHERE MLink.image_sub_type IN ('link ltr') -- Records that does have link ltr ..
    AND MVideo.image_sub_type IS NULL -- .. but no matches on video left join
    AND D.DIRECTORY_ID = 104
```

Comment: Thank you all so far for your answers but I will probably not have a null in that field.

The entry is not created empty so I'm looking for records that have "link ltr" but not a matching "video" to the same "INCIDENT_ID".

Sorry for not explaining it clearly, I'm new to asking for help.

Comment: The left join / is null will do just that - keep the records not matching. But I misunderstood your model. You'll need a self join on Tb_image. Try the updated query.